# Generate data summaries in sharepoint from rows in various excel files

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

We want to have a collection of excel files in different SharePoint sites each send a row of data to another summary excel file in a known SharePoint site to generate reports.

[image]

The problem is that SharePoint doesn't seem to support this kind of thing with the flow since there is no search by capability (you need to know where the file is). We can't have the file itself trigger the flow (i.e: on update) itself since the files are on various sites and this would require duplicate flows.

Thus the only solution I could come to think of would be to have the excel files themselves sync their data as entries to the remote summary excel sheet. I've seen various methods to importing/exporting static data, but the data link needs to update the summary every time the document is changed.

What would be the best way to go about making this work?

Answer (score 0):

> there is no search by capability (you need to know where the file is).

That is not true. Just use `When a file is created or modified (properties only)` trigger pointed to some SharePoint site (no need to select particular folder/in/another/folder)

> We can't have the file itself trigger the flow (i.e: on update)

Half a truth, see above. You did not say what type/form of data you want to share between these Excel files and how often they will be updated. "On update" functionality can be achieved using for e.g `Recurrence` trigger, custom "status" column and filtering.

> files are on various sites and this would require duplicate flows.

Would not as long as flow creator has access to each site (invited).

How about:

- Google Sheets (sheetgo . com),
- using Sharepoint List instead of several Excel spreadsheets,
- PowerQuery fetches files from different sites and consolidate them,